# Map render complete event is not triggered - Openlayers 5

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have written a function in Map render complete event to hide the progress icon if all map tiles are rendered. But the map render complete event is not fired after I added a empty vector layer on map. Below is the code snippet.

```
var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM({
        "url": "http://{a-c}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    })
});
osmLayer.getSource().on('tileloadstart', renderStart);

var extentTransform = ol.proj.transformExtent([minx, miny, maxx, maxy], "EPSG:7844", "EPSG:3857");
osMap = new ol.Map({
    layers: [osmLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        zoom: 11,
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom: 5,
        extent: extentTransform,
        center: ol.extent.getCenter(extentTransform),
        controls: []
    })
});
osMap.on('rendercomplete', renderComplete);

var putStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#900C3F',
        width: 3
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(144, 12, 63, 0.5)'
    })
});   

vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: []
});

var vectorPolygon = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,       
    style: putStyle
});

osMap.addLayer(vectorPolygon);

function renderComplete(event) {
    $(".MapLoadPopup").hide(); // Tile loading progress hide
}

function renderStart(evt) {
    $(".MapLoadPopup").show(); // Tile loading progress show
}

function test(){
    vectorSource.clear();
    var geojsonObject = {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": JSON.parse(polygon),
        }
    };

    var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject);
    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
  }
```

If I commented the `osMap.addLayer(vectorPolygon);` line, the render complete event is triggered correctly. When sourcing this issue in internet, it is came to know that the map render complete event is not fired if we added a vector layer without url.

Myself also tested this case with some url and it is working fine. If so, what could be the solution to overcome this issue.

Comment: In the first place, why do you want to add layer which has no content?

Comment: Yes, I want to clear and add geometries into this layer on map click event. I have added the code for the same above

Comment: Then simply put `osMap.addLayer(vectorPolygon);` inside `renderComplete` function.

Comment: Inside means how? much helpful if you could share piece of code. Thanks

Comment: Between `{` and `}` in function definition: `function renderComplete(event) { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion. Yes it is working now. but often the event is not firing again.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an alternative way for the render complete event to fire the code once all the tiles are rendered on our map. It is working fine for my case.

```
var loading = 0;
var loaded = 0;

osmLayer.getSource().on('tileloadstart', tileLoadStart);
osmLayer.getSource().on('tileloadend', tileLoadEnd);
osmLayer.getSource().on('tileloaderror', tileLoadEnd);
```

//Repeat the same for all layers added on map

```
function tileLoadStart(event) {
  ++loading;
  console.log("Loading : " + loading);
  if (loading === 1) {
    $(".MapLoadPopup").show(); // show loading progress at start of tile load
  }      
}

function tileLoadEnd(event) {
  ++loaded;
  console.log(loading + ' ' + loaded);
  if (loading === loaded) {
    loading = 0;
    loaded = 0;
    $(".MapLoadPopup").hide(); // Tile loading progress hide
  }
}
```